# How to update CPU frequency policy?

Tags: 18.04, cpufreq, frequency

I have an Asus Laptop with i7 + ubuntu 18 (Linux 4.15.0-117-generic)

A few days ago, I don't know how, my PC became very slow. After several investigations I've found that the CPU is always at minimum frequency when on AC, but on battery it's ok.

With Tlp-UI I've updated all CPU parameters to "performance", now the frequency is always at minimum on both AC and battery !!!

`cpupower frequency-info` gave this :

```
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency: 10.0 us
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 2.40 GHz
  available frequency steps:  2.40 GHz, 2.40 GHz, 2.30 GHz, 2.20 GHz, 2.10 GHz, 1.90 GHz, 1.80 GHz, 1.70 GHz, 1.60 GHz, 1.50 GHz, 1.40 GHz, 1.30 GHz, 1.10 GHz, 1000 MHz, 900 MHz, 800 MHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative ondemand userspace powersave performance schedutil
  current policy: frequency should be within 800 MHz and 800 MHz.
                  The governor "userspace" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency: Unable to call hardware
  current CPU frequency: 798 MHz (asserted by call to kernel)
  boost state support:
    Supported: yes
    Active: yes
    25500 MHz max turbo 4 active cores
    25500 MHz max turbo 3 active cores
    25500 MHz max turbo 2 active cores
    25500 MHz max turbo 1 active cores
```

I think this is the problem :

```
current policy: frequency should be within 800 MHz and 800 MHz.
```

I can't figure out how to change that value ! I've tested several ways to do it but nothing happend :

[image]

I found similar problems on the net but nothing works !

**UPDATE**

As requested by @Doug Smythies

```
$ sudo grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver 
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_driver:acpi-cpufreq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_driver:acpi-cpufreq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_driver:acpi-cpufreq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_driver:acpi-cpufreq

$ sudo grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor 
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor:ondemand
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_governor:ondemand
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_governor:ondemand
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_governor:ondemand

$ sudo grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/*
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/affected_cpus:0
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/bios_limit:2401000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq:800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq:2401000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_min_freq:800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_transition_latency:10000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/freqdomain_cpus:0 1 2 3
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/related_cpus:0
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies:2401000 2400000 2300000 2200000 2100000 1900000 1800000 1700000 1600000 1500000 1400000 1300000 1100000 1000000 900000 800000 
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors:conservative ondemand userspace powersave performance schedutil 
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:798224
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_driver:acpi-cpufreq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor:ondemand
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq:800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq:800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed:
grep: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats: Is a directory
```

**UPDATE**

I've ran this :

```
echo 2401000 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq
```

Max frequency updated, but after a reboot modifications are lost ! Something is resetting values in startup, but how to find it ?

**UPDATE**

I've removed TLP and went back to intel-pstate driver. After restart the CPU is always at min frequency on AC but not on battery ! Since my battery is dead and can't hold more than 5 minutes, I think the problem is the AC charger, I've ordered a new one, wait and see ...

**UPDATE**
The new charger have no effect : when I turn the PC on (AC) the CPU works fine, after some minutes it stucks at 800 Mhz ! If I unplug the charger it works fine ! I really don't get it :(

Comment: Is it possible your CPU is overheating?  I searched around a bit and people reported that cleaning out their CPU fan causes the max frequency to return to normal.  It's possible your CPU is self-regulating its clock speed due to heat problems.

Comment: I've cleaned the fan and changed thermal paste 3 months ago ! And as I said, yesterday before idk which tweak, the frequency changed when on battery

Comment: why are you using the userspace governor? And is it set to 800 MHz? Please edit your question adding these outputs: `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver` ; `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor` ; `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/*`.

Comment: Sorry : I've made so many modifications so I really can't answer you ! I've updated the post as requested

Comment: Do: `echo 2401000 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq`. Then check it with: `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq`. If it doesn't stick, then something (TLP?) is re-writting it. Do you know why you are using the acpi-cpufreq driver instead of the intel-pstate driver?

Comment: That current CPU frequency varies as a function of load  is normal, for the ondemand governor. I don't know what is setting scaling_max_freq to minimum. You mentioned TLP, so it is a likely candidate. I never use it or cpupower or any of that stuff, only primitives.